# Couple of questions related to the Apache proxy configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

This is the configuration:

```
<Directory />
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
    Order Deny,Allow
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
    AllowOverride None
    Satisfy any
    Options None FollowSymLinks
</Directory>


<Proxy *>
    Deny from all
    Order Deny,Allow
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy any
    Options None FollowSymLinks
</Proxy>
```

Questions:

1)  Why configured `Proxy *` if already configured `Directory /`?

2)  Should be configured `Proxy *` or `Proxy /`

3)  Should all attributes (e.g. `Deny from all` or `Allow from localhost`) be configured twice (`Proxy` and `Directory`) or enough only in one place? If in one place where it should configured: `Proxy` or `Directory`?

4)  What configuration takes priority `Proxy` or `Directory`?

**Added**
Is order of Directory / Proxy in the configuration file is important?
For example if I have specific `/app` related section should it be before or after the root  section?

```
<Directory /app>
    AuthType None 
</Directory>

<Proxy http://localhost:8080/app >
    AuthType None
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic explanations:

- **URI** is what you see near the top of the browser window. Server sees it in a `HTTP GET xxx ... Host: yyy` at the beginning of each conversation.
- **Frontend** is your apache; generally a server explicitly included into URI, hence contacted by clients (browsers); but frontend only does some intermediary processing of the request, and passes it to other **backend** server, passes back the result. In your case the intermediary processing seems to be TLS/SSL, and backend is Tomcat.
- Apache docs say **reverse proxy** when referring to a frontend. That's a synonym.
- Browsers don't need to know backend and vice versa.
- Browser sends one URI, frontend changes the URI, backend sees a different URI.

Now the actual answer to your question is:

- [The `<Proxy>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy) matches a backend URI.
- [The `<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) matches a real local filesystem directory, something that you can `cd` from the shell.
- Thus the request that matches `<Directory>` quite possibly never matches a `<Proxy>`.

Rest of what you wrote requires either looking into the docs for like a minute, or asking as a separate question on this site.

Comment: Thanks, I have asked the separate question http://serverfault.com/questions/822429/what-should-be-configured-in-ajp-proxy-configuration.  Any case I will happy to clarify if I need to configure attributes twice or once. in addition I will happy for one additional clarification that I have added to the question (I can ask in the separate question).